# Calculate slot machine game multiplier

Tags: gambling

I'm developing a slot machine game with **5 slots**, each slot has **6 options** (pear, lemon, ..., etc.).

Each spin, 5 random values get generated, one for each slot, making the slots spin to the option bound to their random number. **When 3 or more consecutive numbers get generated in a spin** eg.: (12444 or 42223 or 11111) the player "wins" the spin.

The won amount should be calculated depending on the number of consecutive equal numbers in a won spin, the amount the player bet that spin, and the value of the consecutive numbers (**1 should be worth less than 6**).

See included [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70zmj.png) for an example win chart, in short the question would be: **how can I calculate the multiplier for each option** (eg. 25* 5* in the image) which would result in a **+-48% chance of making a profit** on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't exactly nice formulas for these things; you just have to use inclusion/exclusion.

If all six symbols are equally likely, the chance of getting all five the same is the chance that the left symbol matches each of the subsequent ones,

$(1/6)^4 = 1/1296$.

The chance of getting exactly four in a row is the chance of getting the first four in a row, plus the chance of getting the last four in a row, minus twice the chance of getting all five in a row (since this is counted twice, once in each case).  So that's

$2(1/6)^3 - 2(1/6)^4 = 5/648$

The chance of getting three in a row can be calculated similarly with an uglier expression.

Then you just pick numbers to make the probability come out to what you want; there are lots of potential solutions.

That said, you probably want to optimize the expected value rather than the chance of winning, assuming the payout is higher for four in a row than for three in a row.